# Obtain optimal number of boosting iterations in GradientBoostingClassifier using grid search

Tags: python, scikit-learn

With `GradientBoostingClassifier` suppose I set `n_estimators` to `2000` and use `GridSearchCV` to search across `learning_rate` in `[0.01, 0.05, 0.10]` - how do I know the number of boosting iterations that produced the optimal result - is the model always going to fit `2000` trees for each value of `learning_rate` or is it going to use the optimal number of boosting iterations for each of these values? It wouldn't make sense to also include `n_estimators` in the grid search and search for all values in `[1,2000]`.

Comment: It will currently use exactly 2000 estimators and indeed you would need to search over ``n_estimators`` if you want to use ``GridSearchCV`` with ``GradientBoostingClassifier``.
You are right, that is not very efficient, but we haven't implemented a better method yet (there are some api issues).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. So in a grid search setting how would I find the knee of the test/cross validation curve to get my final model and use it for prediction (on the lines of the ~`150 iteration` point for the red line in the plot: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html)? Also does the same observation hold when you are building an ensemble of trees (Random Forest, AdaBoost)?

Comment: Usually you want the minimum test set error, which you can get as ``grid_search.best_params_`` (or by just using ``grid_search.predict``). For Random Forests, more trees is always better, but with diminishing returns. There is no smart search for number of estimators in any of these yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Just to clarify: the `best_params` is going to pick from the set of estimators I provide and not use the optimum number of iterations, right? _e.g.,_: `numTrees=[500,1000], params2Tune={'n_estimators':numTrees}, gsObj=GridSearchCV(GradientBoostingClassifier(), params2Tune)`. The resulting `gsObj.predict()` would fit exactly `gsObj.best_params_['n_estimators']` trees, and this can be only `500` or `1000` trees, even though say `197` iterations/trees would have been the optimum (the knee of the curve), right?

Comment: Yes, these will be the only two settings that will be evaluated by GridSearchCV.

Comment: I don't know why I am not able to mark this question as answered (green flag). I don't see any flag to the left of the answers!

Comment: Because I commented on it, not answered it. Ill answer, too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to directly get the optimum number of estimators from GradientBoostingClassifier. If you also pass `n_estimators` in the parameter grid to `GridSearchCV` it will only try the exact values you give it, and return one of these.
We are looking to improve this, by searching over the number of estimators automatically.